# IntelliJ IDEA: Can I specify which class is in "secure context"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, inspection

"Clonable class in secure context" inspection triggers if a class implements `Cloneable`. The name of the inspection implies that it is only applied to classes which are in a "secure context".

How does IntelliJ decide if a class is in a secure context?

How do I tell IntelliJ whether a class is in a secure context or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only supposed to run the inspection on the "secure context" (by using a scope). Perhaps the description of this inspection could be improved. See here for more explanation:
- https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/OBJ07-J.+Sensitive+classes+must+not+let+themselves+be+copied
- http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/498.html

Comment: Do you mean the inspection is not intended to be enabled by default, but rather should only used in "Run Inspection By Name...". Or do you mean, I am supposed to change the default inspection setting of "Warning in all Scopes" to a custom scope created by me?

Comment: The second, except if your entire project is in a "secure context" :-)